# @change not working with select tag in Vue3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I tried `@change` and `watch` as well. None of them seem to work.

How to detect when select value is changed?

Here is my code:

```
 <select v-model="selected" @change="changeLang()" >
    <option v-for="item in langList" :key="item.text" :value="item.lang">
      {{ item.text }}
    </option>
 </select>

function changeLang()
{
   console.log("Called>>>>");
}

watch(() => selected, (first, second) => {
      console.log(
        "Watch props.selected function called with args:",
        first,
        second
      );
});
```

Comment: had you tried to bind your `v-model` on each single item? The documentation will give you a hint to [solve it with v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox) instead of a watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const selected = ref(null)
    const langList = ref([{text:'en', lang: 'english'}, {text:'de', lang: 'deutsch'}, {text:'it', lang:'italian'}])
    
    const changeLang = () => {
      console.log("Called>>>>", selected.value);
    }

    return {
      selected, langList, changeLang
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select v-model="selected" @change="changeLang()" >
    <option v-for="item in langList" :key="item.text" :value="item.lang">
      {{ item.text }}
    </option>
 </select>
</div>
```